# MySQL: select row in parent table that has two rows in child table (one to many)

Tags: mysql

I have two tables "parent" and "child" with one to many relationship.

I wish to grab all records from "parent" table who's rows in "child" table have status 'pending' and 'approved'

e.g.
"manufacturers" table:

```
id, name 
1, Boots
2, Audi
3, AVG
```

"models" table:

```
id, manufacturer_id, status (int) 
1, 1, pending
2, 1, failed
3, 1, approved
4, 2, failed
5, 3, approved
```

I want to grab all the manufacturers that have models with status "pending" and "approved". Given the above data mysql should return "Boots" because in "models" Boots has a record with status "pending" (id = 1) and "approved" (id = 5)

Comment: hey, wait :-) you confused everybody :-) on one hand `status (int)` on other `'pending','failed','approved'` so what is your type for `status` column?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following query to get the ids of those manufacturers that are related to both `status`, `1` and `5`:

```
SELECT manufacturer_id
FROM models
WHERE status IN (1,5)
GROUP BY manufacturer_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT status) = 2
```

You can now use the above query as a subquery in order to get the expected result set:

```
SELECT *
FROM manufacturers
WHERE id IN ( ... above query here ...)
```

Comment: `..status in (1,5)...`

Comment: @1000111 Yes, you are right, I've corrected my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct man.name from manufacturers man, models mod
where man.id = mod.manufacturer_id
and mod.status in ('pending', 'approved')
```

Answer (score 0):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9c1e32/3

```
SELECT m.*
FROM manufacturers m
JOIN models
ON m.id = models.manufacturer_id
GROUP BY m.id
HAVING MAX(IF(models.status=1,1,0))+MAX(IF(models.status=2,1,0))=2
```

**Update** I have no idea why you changed your OP, but if your `status` is not int anymore you can:

```
SELECT m.*
FROM manufacturers m
JOIN models
ON m.id = models.manufacturer_id
GROUP BY m.id
HAVING MAX(IF(models.status='pending',1,0))+MAX(IF(models.status='approved',1,0))=2
```